# Jackson 2 deserialization

Tags: android, jackson

I have a problem using google geocoding api. For example, with this url http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=47.3195254,5.0430687&sensor=true, I want to parse the json with jackson 2 to create the POJO.

So my class is

```
public class GeocoderResult {

@JsonProperty("results") private List<GeocoderGoog> geocoder;
@JsonProperty("status") private String status;

public List<GeocoderGoog> getGeocoder() {
    return geocoder;
}
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

}
```

To deserialize json, I use

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(baseUrl).openConnection();
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// disable exceptions when there is unknown properties
mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
Log.d(Constants.D_TAG, "Status : "+statusCode);
if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {  // 200
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    status = (Status) mapper.readValue(is, GeocoderResult.class);
}
```

I have the following error :

```
09:38:42.737 Thread-24889 An exception occurred during request network execution :Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']' (for ROOT starting at [Source: java.io.BufferedInputStream@428a1840; line: 1, column: 0])                                       
 at [Source: java.io.BufferedInputStream@428a1840; line: 2, column: 14]
 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected close marker '}': expected ']' (for ROOT starting at [Source: java.io.BufferedInputStream@428a1840; line: 1, column: 0])
```

I don't understand where is the problem ...

ps : I use jackson-core, jackson-databind and jackson-annotations 2.1.4

Comment: JSON you are getting is invalid -- some content is missing, most likely. Nothing to do with data-binding, exception comes straight from streaming parser.

Comment: It can be a problem with the version of jackson ?

Comment: No. Read the exception message. Version incompatibilities give pretty distinct errors from class-loading. This indicates broken JSON input -- why that is the case I can not speculate. You can tackle that by first reading and buffering content, then giving it to parser -- and perhaps logging the input for trouble-shooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a fan of Jackson and I can say you made me curious. I used the URL you exposed and make it work like below. **Used the current API version: 2.2.3**

Model classes:

**GeocoderResult**

```
public class GeocoderResult {

    @JsonProperty("results")
    private ArrayList<GeocoderGoog> geocoder;

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;

    public ArrayList<GeocoderGoog> getGeocoder() {
        return geocoder;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}
```

**GeocoderGoog**

```
public class GeocoderGoog {

    @JsonProperty("address_components")
    private ArrayList<AddressComponent> addressComponents;

    @JsonProperty("formatted_address")
    private String formattedAddress;

    private ArrayList<String> types;

    private Geometry geometry;

    public ArrayList<AddressComponent> getAddressComponents() {
        return addressComponents;
    }

    public String getFormattedAddress() {
        return formattedAddress;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTypes() {
        return types;
    }

    public Geometry getGeometry() {
        return geometry;
    }

}
```

**AddressComponent**

```
public class AddressComponent {
    @JsonProperty("long_name")
    private String longName;

    @JsonProperty("short_name")
    private String shortName;

    private ArrayList<String> types;

    public String getLongName() {
        return longName;
    }

    public String getShortName() {
        return shortName;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getTypes() {
        return types;
    }

}
```

A **Coordinates** used in other classes

```
public class Coordinates {
    private double lat;
    private double lng;

    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(double lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public double getLng() {
        return lng;
    }

    public void setLng(double lng) {
        this.lng = lng;
    }

}
```

and a **Geometry** with **Viewport**:

```
public class Geometry {
    private Coordinates location;

    @JsonProperty("location_type")
    private String locationType;

    private ViewPort viewport;

    public Coordinates getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public String getLocationType() {
        return locationType;
    }

    public ViewPort getViewport() {
        return viewport;
    }

    public static class ViewPort {
        private Coordinates northeast;
        private Coordinates southwest;

        public Coordinates getNortheast() {
            return northeast;
        }

        public Coordinates getSouthwest() {
            return southwest;
        }

    }
}
```

and to wrap it up - for me this worked from first attempt:

```
protected void performJackson() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                String baseUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=47.3195254,5.0430687&sensor=true";
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(baseUrl).openConnection();
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                // disable exceptions when there is unknown properties
                mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
                int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
                Log.d("SJackson", "Status : " + statusCode);
                if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) { // 200
                    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
                    GeocoderResult result = mapper.readValue(is, GeocoderResult.class);
                    Log.d("SJackson", "Done: " + (result != null));
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("SJackson", null, ex);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: Why `Coordinates` class is not annotated ?

Comment: You don't need to annotate a class ... you need to annotate class instances

Comment: I mean, it should be `@JsonProperty("lat") private double lat` and `@JsonProperty("lng") private double lng`, isn't it ? Moreover I must use ArrayList instead of List ?

Comment: You don't need to annotate if names match (like in this case). Related to ArrayList, I must say this is something I am used from previous JSON parsers. Feel free to use List as its more practical. It should work as well.

Comment: Ok, so I have the same model except I use List and I get the error above. I will check again but the error message is not clear ...

Comment: Just make a separate project and use the code EXACTLY how I gave you. Then feel free to compare the differences and you'll see where it's wrong. One more thing: I'm using the latest Jackson API - I believe it's 2.2.3

Comment: Sorry, I've not enough time to start again a project. I've used another solution (not very good) but I will test again your solution tomorrow or Saturday. I will give you feedback

Comment: Dude, you have all the code in front of you ... CTRL+C and then CTRL+V!

Comment: And ? I've not enough time ! I must do a build today and I don' t understand what is the problem with jackson so for the moment I 've had a fix and I'll try again your solution another day ...

Comment: Okay your solution works like a charm ! If I take your code and place in my project, I have this error. If I use Asynctask instead of robospice library, it works too so i think the problem is here